# Handling dependency on Future completion in Scala Play (2.6) EssentialFilter

Tags: scala, playframework, future

Suppose I have an `EssentialFilter` called `AbcFilter` whose purpose is to add a header to each request. However, to decide what it needs to add, it has to make a call to a library that returns a `Future`. The way I have currently implemented it makes use of `Await`, since I need the `Future` to complete so I know how to construct the header I need to add. Here is the implementation:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.duration.{Duration, _}
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

class AbcFilter () extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextFilter: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
       // This call returns a future
       val future: Future[String] = asyncLibrary.doSomething(requestHeader)
       //Is there any way to avoid using Await here?
       val futureResult = Await.result[String](future, Duration(5, SECONDS))
       val newHeader = "New-Header-Name"-> futureResult 
       //I do need the future to complete in order to create this header!
       val data = requestHeader.headers.toSimpleMap.toSeq :+ newHeader
       val newHeaders = new Headers(_headers = data)
       nextFilter(requestHeader.withHeaders(newHeaders))
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to implement this without the `Await`?

Comment: Which version of play? 2.6.x has the shape in that it returns a `Future[Response]`.

Comment: It is 2.6 - however I don't want to return a Future[Response] I want to invoke nextFilter() with the request that contains the new headers.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using `Await`, stay within the context of a `Future`:

```
class AbcFilter () extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextFilter: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
      val newHeaderFut: Future[(String, String)] = asyncLibrary.doSomething(requestHeader)
        .map(s => "New-Header-Name" -> s)

      val newHeaders: Future[Headers] = newHeaderFut.map(requestHeader.headers.add)

      val accumulator: Accumulator[ByteString, Result] = nextFilter(requestHeader)
      accumulator.mapFuture { result =>
        newHeaders.map(h => result.withHeaders(h.headers: _*))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this add the headers to the Result instead of the request?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using Filter instead of EssentialFilter and using flatMap. The flatMap could be applied to the first future we get in the below code sample, but hopefully this provides an idea of the pattern.

```
    class AbcFilter () extends Filter{
      def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
        (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
          val newHeaderFut: Future[(String, String)] = asyncLibrary.doSomething(requestHeader)
            .map(s => "New-Header-Name" -> s)
          val newHeaders: Future[Headers] = newHeaderFut.map(requestHeader.headers.add)
          newHeaders.flatMap { h => { nextFilter(requestHeader.withHeaders(newHeaders))
           }
         }                 
       }        
     }      
   } }
```